# Angular Reactive forms don't wait for custom async validators

Tags: angular, validation, authentication, angular-cli, angular-reactive-forms

I have a login component in my angular-CLI app. I have fields email and password. I created two custom validations => one for checking if the user exists, and other for checking if the password matches the user. I checked the working of built-in validators like a required field and valid email. They work fine. The problem is that my custom validators show errors only after the submission is called. **The reactive form is not waiting for the custom async validators to resolve.**

This is my code:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {AuthService} from '../auth.service';
import {noUser, pwdMisMatch} from '../validators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;
  returnUrl: string;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, public authService: AuthService) {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
        password: ['', Validators.required],
      },
      {
        validators: [noUser(authService, 'email'), pwdMisMatch(authService, 'email', 'password')]
        , updateOn: 'blur'
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.returnUrl = '/dashboard';
    this.authService.logout();
  }

  get f() {
    return this.form.controls;
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;

    // stop here if form is invalid
    if (this.form.invalid) {
      return;
    } else {
      alert('Success');
    }
  }

}
```

This is my custom validators file:

```
import {FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';
import {AuthResponse, AuthService} from './auth.service';

export function MustMatch(controlName: string, matchingControlName: string) {
  return (formGroup: FormGroup) => {
    const control = formGroup.controls[controlName];
    const matchingControl = formGroup.controls[matchingControlName];

    if (matchingControl.errors && !matchingControl.errors.mustMatch) {
      // return if another validator has already found an error on the matchingControl
      return;
    }

    // set error on matchingControl if validation fails
    if (control.value !== matchingControl.value) {
      matchingControl.setErrors({ mustMatch: true });
    } else {
      matchingControl.setErrors(null);
    }
  };
}

export function userExist(authservice: AuthService, controlName: string) {
  return (formGroup: FormGroup) => {
    const control = formGroup.controls[controlName];

    if (control.errors && !control.errors.CheckUser) {
      // return if another validator has already found an error on the matchingControl
      return;
    }

    // set error on matchingControl if validation fails
    authservice.checkUser(control.value).subscribe((res: AuthResponse) => {
      if (res.ok) {
        control.setErrors({ userExist: true });
      } else {
        control.setErrors(null);
      }
    });
  };
}

export function noUser(authService: AuthService, controlName: string) {
  return (formGroup: FormGroup) => {
    const control = formGroup.controls[controlName];

    if (control.errors && !control.errors.noUser) {
      // return if another validator has already found an error on the matchingControl
      return;
    }

    // set error on matchingControl if validation fails
    authService.checkUser(control.value).subscribe((res: AuthResponse) => {
      if (!res.ok) {
        control.setErrors({ noUser: true });
      } else {
        control.setErrors(null);
      }
    });
  };
}

export function pwdMisMatch(authService: AuthService, controlName: string, secureControlName: string) {
  return (formGroup: FormGroup) => {
    const control = formGroup.controls[controlName];
    const secureControl = formGroup.controls[secureControlName];

    if (control.errors || secureControl.errors && !secureControl.errors.pwdMisMatch) {
      // return if another validator has already found an error on the matchingControl
      return;
    }

    // set error on matchingControl if validation fails
    authService.verifyPassword(control.value, secureControl.value).subscribe((res: AuthResponse) => {
      if (!res.ok) {
        secureControl.setErrors({ pwdMisMatch: true });
      } else {
        control.setErrors(null);
      }
    });
  };
}
```

I tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49516084/reactive-angular-form-to-wait-for-async-validator-complete-on-submit) and the problem is not solved. Please help.

Update: [my angular repo](https://github.com/iamsrk/angular-auth)

Comment: You mean before submitting the form the on submit get called?

Comment: no no, the value of "this.form.invalid" fails and the success message is displayed before the custom form validation is resolved.

Comment: I need to make the form to be invalid until the custom validations are complete. I don't think setting the value manually is a good way.

Comment: Is there any way to make the reactive form to wait for custom validation to resolve. that execute submit function only if the form validations are complete

Comment: Have you tried FormGroup pending property?

Comment: I added my angular repo for you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should identify as an async validators, like that :

```
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, public authService: AuthService) {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group(
        {
            email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
            password: ['', Validators.required],
        },
        {
            asyncValidators: [noUser(authService, 'email'), pwdMisMatch(authService, 'email', 'password')]
            , updateOn: 'blur'
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: I tried your answer, I gave a valid email for which the error " no user found" is displayed. but the form submission code is also running.

Comment: the form didn't wait for the validation to complete

Comment: I added my angular repo for you

Answer (score 1):

Angular customValidator function should return error or null in order to work.

FormGroup has pending status you can use that to check whether the async validator has completed or not.

**Try this:**

```
export function noUser(authService: AuthService, controlName: string) {
  return (formGroup: FormGroup) => {
    const control = formGroup.controls[controlName];

    if (control.errors && !control.errors.noUser) {
      // return if another validator has already found an error on the matchingControl
      return;
    }

    // set error on matchingControl if validation fails
    authService.checkUser(control.value).subscribe((res: AuthResponse) => {
      if (!res.ok) {
        return { noUser: true };
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    });
  };
}

export function pwdMisMatch(authService: AuthService, controlName: string, secureControlName: string) {
  return (formGroup: FormGroup) => {
    const control = formGroup.controls[controlName];
    const secureControl = formGroup.controls[secureControlName];

    if (control.errors || secureControl.errors && !secureControl.errors.pwdMisMatch) {
      // return if another validator has already found an error on the matchingControl
      return;
    }

    // set error on matchingControl if validation fails
    authService.verifyPassword(control.value, secureControl.value).subscribe((res: AuthResponse) => {
      if (!res.ok) {
        rerurn { pwdMisMatch: true };
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    });
  };
}

 onSubmit() {
        this.submitted = true;

        // stop here if form is invalid
        if (this.form.pending && this.form.invalid) {
          return;
        } else {
          alert('Success');
        }
      }
```

Comment: This didn't do any change. The form behaves as before

Comment: I tried your answer, and the error keeps happening. with which I found that the success message is displayed before the form validation is triggered!

Comment: I added my angular repo for you

Comment: I don't get any error but the reactive form executes the submission code despite validation fails.

Comment: you mean invalid false?

Comment: If you console inside subscribe method is it get printed in console?

Comment: Its the reactive form's bug

Comment: or something I am missing

Comment: what to do for backend?

Answer (score 0):

The issue that your async validations functions are not return Promise or Observable

From angular documentation:

> Async validators: functions that take a control instance and return a Promise or Observable that later emits a set of validation errors or null. You can pass these in as the third argument when you instantiate a FormControl

Dont use Subscribe here:

```
authservice.checkUser(control.value).subscribe()
```

use pipe() transformation instead:

```
authservice.checkUser(control.value). pipe(map(res => res && res.ok ? ({ userExist: true }) : null ))
```

Comment: I tried your answer. it didn't work. also, it fails to add errors like " userExist: true ". The error is not even showing in the form.

Comment: What do you mean 'not showing'? Have you try to debug with ng.probe($0).componentInstance in console?

Comment: checkUser(email: any) {
    const url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/user';
    const headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
    const body: any = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({ email }));
    const options = { headers };
    return this.http.post(url, body, options)
      .pipe(
        map(data => new AuthResponse(data))
      );
  }

Comment: should I pipe again?

Comment: It's okey. Are you sure that you dont have exception on Json.parse and stringify?

Comment: I added my angular repo for you